# npm3 does not flatten a dependency structure completely

Tags: npm, npm-install

npm3 brought to use dependencies flattening so that a `node_modules` folder is flat. Apparently that's not always true. I have my application, let's name it `A` and a module I'm developing, `B`. That module has `gulp` as a dependency and some `gulp` plugins, like `gulp-rename`. I was expecting to have `gulp` and `gulp-rename` in the `node-modules` folder of my app `A` (as it has `B` as a dependency). But this is not the case. `gulp-rename` is in fact in `A/node_modules` but `gulp` itself is in `A/node_modules/B/node_modules` folder.

Any clues why is this happening?

**UPDATE**

I've narrowed down the issue to this particular case:

Having an app `A` and a module I'm developing, `B`. That module has `gulp` as a dependency and a package.json `bin` property defined as following (`B`'s package.json):

`javascript 
"bin" {
    "gulp": "<some_valid_path>"
}`

I was expecting to have `gulp` in the `node-modules` folder of my app `A` (as it has `B` as a dependency and because of npm3 dependency flattening). But apparently npm leaves it in `A/node_modules/B/node_modules` folder. Is it an intended behaviour and why?

Answer (score 1):

Well, `npm` flattens your dependency tree as much as possible; this however does not mean it's always entirely flat. For example, if your dependency D1 depends on A ^1.0.0 and D2 depends on A ^2.0.0, `npm` obviously cannot put both these dependencies to the root `node_modules` simultaneously. One version of A (say 1.0.0) may go to the root, the other must go to the `node_modules/D2/node_modules` such that D2 finds A in correct version before it even starts looking for it in a parent dir.

Comment: Yes, that's what docs say but I have `gulp` only once in my dependency tree.

Comment: Well, that's strange. Two things come to mind: 1) can you please double check, there is only one `gulp` in the dependency tree? Maybe something else also depends on it? 2) maybe there is some (unknown, for me) way of specifying for a package, it does not want to share a dependency.

Comment: Also, could you post your `package.json` so I can reproduce this?